# How to parse ipa using php to collect informations

Tags: php, parsing, ipa

I want to parse a file .ipa from apple to get informations about, like name, app_version, etc ...

Or read a .plist file in php :
When I unzip a ipa file I have a file ' info.plist ', I think this one have all the informations i am looking for.

Someone knows how to do it ?

Comment: In the file. Maybe you should change your question to give us some more information.

Comment: Ok, I would like to retrieve app information from a .ipa in php.

Comment: "a .ipa" isn't information. There are millions of .ipa's, tell us exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried and why it didn't work - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, I need to do a webapp, to store apk's and ipa's, and generate a nice web page to download the .apk's and .ipa's. To generate my web page, i need informations about the app like the name or the version to put it in my web page and get a link like : 'you are about to download the version 'IPA_version' of 'IPA_name'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finaly found the answer. To get app informations from the .ipa, you need to :

- unzip the .ipa
- find the Info.plist file (which content the informations about the app)
- then parse it (I did it with this library https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList )